# ActiveXObject ('word.application') Open returns undefined

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, activexobject

I am using ActiveXObject ('word.application') to open and process Word document as follows:

```
var w = new ActiveXObject ('word.application');
var doc = w.Documents.Open(sFileToOpen);
```

but `doc` comes back is `undefined`. File does exist and can be opened fine. We have this exact code in our production environment and it works there. Apparently I am missing something on my machine. Do I need to install some tool? This is definitely not a code problem.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have Word? And are you running that in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I do have word. Tried this with Word running with some document open (different from the one I am trying to process) and closed. I am trying this in IE, but this shouldn't matter, cause this is a server side code

Comment: Ah, so it's server-side JScript? In that case, I believe you must have Word on the server.

Comment: Right, but I am running it locally, so my machine IS the server. Maybe I need a different kind of Word, or a tool of some sort that acts like Word?

Comment: I don't know... Out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: if it's server side code, shouldn't you be using Server.CreateObject instead of new ActiveXobject.

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question but it's worth reading - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 2):

Though very late but still answering here.

I tried somwthing like this, and it worked for me.

```
var wordDoc = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
if (wordDoc !== null){
    wordDoc.Visible = true;
 wordDoc.Documents.Open('C:\\Users\\msiddiq1\\Desktop\\One10DandOne9P.docx');
}
```

Just that i used two backslashes.